Why does my test loss and test evaluation metrics fluctuate?
I am fine-tuning the resnet18 model with additional classifiers. What I observed during the training process, is that test loss and other test evaluation metrics (AP, AUC) seem to fluctuate as you can see in the .
Towards the later epochs, it does seem to converge into a more stable range, but I am still curious why loss and metric fluctuates up and down in the initial training stage?
I do not understand why test loss and evaluation metric fluctuate.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
